# React Native: Screen is freezing issue after closing Modal by Swipe down

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having an issue in React Native, I have a screen where I have a to-do list along with search bar, on click on any todo item It opens a Modal where It has close button and content.

On closing the Modal by pressing close button, It's working fine but, when I am doing swipe down my screen is freezing, I am unable to scroll and tab on todo list item also unable to press the search bar to type.

also, on swipe down popup is closing but its not triggering `onRequestClose` and `onDismiss`

**React Native Version**

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
```

**Modal code**

```
creditCardsModalVisibleHandler = (visible) => {
    this.setState({creditCardsModalVisible: visible});
}

<Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={false}
    visible={creditCardsModalVisible}
    presentationStyle="formSheet"
    onDismiss={() => {
        console.log('Close handled');
        this.creditCardsModalSwipeHandler();
    }}
    onRequestClose={() => {
        console.log('Modal has been closed');
        this.creditCardsModalSwipeHandler();
    }}
>
    <View style={[modal.main]}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.creditCardsModalVisibleHandler(!creditCardsModalVisible);}}>
            <View style={[modal.closeButton]}>
                <ImageBackground source={modal.closeBackgroundImage} style={[modal.closeButtonImage]}/>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</Modal>
```